# Stop Ruby from Automatically Escaping Strings

Tags: ruby, escaping

If I have the string `"this is a \#test"` and I drop it into the Python shell, I get back `'this is a \\#test'`, which is the behavior I am looking for.  But if I drop it into a Ruby shell, I get back `"this is a #test"` with no indication that a backslash had been present.  How do I make the Ruby string behave like Python, that is, without automatically escaping my # sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using single quotes when you dont want escape sequences interpreted.

```
[1] pry(main)> 'this is a \#test'
=> "this is a \\#test"
```

Single quotes will also not do string interpolation, so if you need *both*, you can escape your slash manually:

```
[1] pry(main)> t = "test" ; "this is a \\##{t}"
=> "this is a \\#test"
```

Comment: Are single quotes the default behavior for the `gets` method?

Comment: The `gets` method won't do any interpolation or escape sequences.  It doesn't have anything to do with quoting -- it's just reading characters from standard input.

Comment: @Kvass: Gets will never escape characters.

Comment: How to do this if the strings are stored in some file?

Answer (score 2):

Just use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
'this is a \#test'
```

Will include the backslash. In Ruby, only `"` strings do substitution and escaping. `'` strings only escape `\\` to `\`